# Routing to specific port

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2

i don't have much knowledge about dns records and devops things. I'm just trying to achieve ;

I have an Ec2 instance on amazon. I create a CNAME record for and successfully redirected to ec2 instance.

I would like to know is it possible to subdomain to given port number for ec2 instance i mean; I have 2 node.js applications are running on my ec2 server one of them is listening to 80 port which is providing web content. CNAME record is just working fine with that application.

My other application is listening to 5575 port. i would like to have . that is point to ec2's 5575 port. is it possible to have something like that. I found SRV record thing but i'm not sure if it's correct record type for me.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible and not necessary to point a domain name at a specific port, in or out of EC2. Just create a CNAME pointing the domain name at the instance, and you'll be able to load http://:5575/ (assuming that your security groups allow it).

Comment: I'm already able to reach it via <mydomain.com>:5575 but i would liket to reach it with <subdomain>.<mydomain.com> without any port number. I guess i was clear about it ^^.